# Deleting from a standalone index, does not reflect on the index where the deleted entity is used as @IndexedEmbedded

Tags: hibernate-search

We are using hibernate search 5.9.2.

We have two entities with A and B. A has One-To-Many relationship with B. And we are using them as below:

```
@Entity
@Indexed(index="master_index")
public class A{

        @IndexedEmbedded
    private Set<B> b= new HashSet<>(0);
        //Setter and getter for b

}

@Entity
@Indexed(index = "b")
public class B{
    @ContainedIn
    private A a;
        //Setter and getter for a
}
```

One-to-Many relationship is defined under the .hbm files.

Now when some record is deleted from index B directly(but through hibernate process) the same record is not deleted from 'master-index'.

Let us assume I have a record 'xyz' which is available under index B and is also available under 'A' with a relationship like DUDE(data of A) can contain many data like 'xyz'.

DUDE->xyz

The expected result should be the record should delete from index 'b' as well as from the 'master-index'.

Does hibernate search provides a way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identified the reason, why this was not working. Will try to provide those findings below:

Initially in my older code, our system was fetching the to be deleted data with a query and then a executeUpdate() was fired and it was not deleting the data using the session.delete(). And due to this the hibernate cache was not aware of the deletion of the object.

Below is the old and new code:

**Older Version:**

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("deleteBySeqnumRec");   
            query.setLong("seqnum", seqnum);    
            int result = query.executeUpdate(); 
            status.setNumOfRows(result);
```

**New Version**

```
DataTO dataTO = selectById(new DataTO, seqnum);
            if(!dataTO.isRecNotFound()) {
                session.delete(dataTO);
                status.setNumOfRows(1);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Identified the reason, why this was not working. Will try to provide those findings below:

Initially in my older code, our system was fetching the to be deleted data with a query and then a executeUpdate() was fired and it was not deleting the data using the session.delete(). And due to this the hibernate cache was not aware of the deletion of the object.

Below is the old and new code:

**Older Version:**

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("deleteBySeqnumRec");   
            query.setLong("seqnum", seqnum);    
            int result = query.executeUpdate(); 
            status.setNumOfRows(result);
```

**New Version**

```
DataTO dataTO = selectById(new DataTO, seqnum);
            if(!dataTO.isRecNotFound()) {
                session.delete(dataTO);
                status.setNumOfRows(1);
            }
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Search expects bi-directional associations to be updated consistently on both sides.

This means that, when you delete `B`, you are expected to remove it from `A.b`. This will cause a change in entity `A`, which will trigger reindexing of the entity.

If `A` wasn't reindexed, it probably means you forgot to remove `B` from `A.b`.

Comment: Thank You @yrodiere,
Are you suggesting to manually fire a delete on the index for A.b deletion. Or that should be taken care by the Hibernate search.
Further, is this scenario been taken care by HIbernate search in the later versions than 5.9.2.

Comment: I'm suggesting to call `a.b.remove( ... )` to actually remove your instance of `B` being deleted. Upgrading from 5.9.2 wouldn't help: behavior is the same in later versions of Hibernate Search. There are technical constraints that prevent us to improve on this in new versions: we can't just call getters on deleted entities, because some calls would trigger exceptions due to lazy-loading from a deleted entity.